# UDP sending important data often - Should I use a reliable send or unreliable with resend?

Tags: multiplayer, synchronization, raknet

I'm making a multiplayer RPG. My problem is that I send player data very often (100 ms), that contains:

- Position (float x, y, z)
- Radius (float angle)
- Animation (int16_t id)

And because the package is unreliable, sometimes packets are lost and here the problem starts. The packet is only sent if something changes, like animation; but animation is important, they must arrive to the clients.

So the question is, should I change reliability to reliable? Or just split packet into two? Or simply resend packet?

Comment: what is radius and animation? What are they representing? What kind of game are you making?

Comment: animation is 16 bit int that, represents the id of animation, and radius is an float, that represents angle. This is the RPG game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd never heard of Raknet prior to this post, but I looked a bit at the information [contained here](http://www.raknet.net/raknet/manual/reliabilitytypes.html).  I would agree that the queuing of data with `PacketReliability.Reliable` seems like it could be problematic, though it looks like your packets are pretty small.  It appears like you could probably use `PacketReliability.Unreliable_With_ACK_Receipt` and create your own queue pending the ACK for things that may require it, and letting things that don't continue to fire at will.

Frankly, the Reliable datatype seems far less efficient than just using TCP and letting the network control most of the verification of data.

Answer (score 0):

Reliable sending is for data that "must" reach the target, or otherwise can cause unexpected behaviour.

Unreliable sending is for data that has no significance on it's own, and can be replaced easily with next packages.

The problem with reliable sending is, once a package is lost, all pending packages gets into a queue until the lost package is successfully sent to target. So using reliable sending for position and rotation can cause serious hiccups on player positions (aka teleporting, lagging). Because of this, I'd use unreliable sending for positions and rotations.

If you are having problems with packets lost for position and rotation sync, you should reconstruct your algorithm; because position and rotation should be overwritten by the most recent packages received.

Comment: Currently I'm using unreliable_sequenced, but like I said, what about the animation? Should I split it into two packets? One with unrealiable_sequenced and one with reliable?

Comment: @Mr.Nobody If you are talking about sending animation states, that's about the pace of your game. If it is fast paced, use unreliable; otherwise use reliable.